# "incompatible types" in foreach with jdk 1.7 - no error with 1.6

Tags: java, java-7

I have code similar to the following which compiles with jdk 1.6.0_22 but not with jdk 1.7.0_79:

```
for(Entry<A, B> entry: aBean.getData().entrySet()) { }
```

`getData()` returns a `Map<A, B>`. With 1.7 the following compile error occurs, suggesting that the generics of the returned Set are erased:

```
[compile] /path/to/file.java:170: error: incompatible types
[compile] for (Entry<A, B> entry: aBean.getData().entrySet()) {
[compile] ^
[compile] required: Entry<A, B>
[compile] found: Object
```

The error disappears when I use a local variable to hold the Set:

```
Set<Entry<A, B>> mySet = aBean.getData().entrySet();
for(Entry<A, B> entry: mySet) { } //works
```

Given that this compiles under 1.6, am I correct in assuming this is a compile Bug? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you also get the compilation error if you write __for(java.util.Map.Entry<A, B> entry: aBean.getData().entrySet()){}__? I tried your original code on my jdk 1.7.0_79, and it worked perfectly fine. Which class (including package path) is "Entry" in the second, compiling example? It might be that aBean.getData() returns not java.util.Map but another, self-defined Map class.

Comment: No, @subrunner, the method returns a HashMap. As evident by the fact that the code compiles when I extract the method call to a local variable, both the map and the entry import work just as expected. And the same compile error is still thrown when I use either Map.Entry or java.util.Map.Entry instead.

Comment: What happens if you don't save the entrySet but the map itself to a local variable? Does that compile?

Comment: @subrunner yes, that compiles as well. This seems more and more like a compiler bug...

Answer (score -1):

Have you already tested this with Java 8? If the issue still exists with the latest – and only supported – Java version, I suggest you create a [bug report](http://bugs.java.com).

Otherwise use the solution you already provided in your question.